# Get the previous date from today's date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to plot a graph by fetching the previous seven days using the present day in Javascript.

Which should pass through the tests of Leap year, days of mont(30/31), Year change.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: subtract one from the day - don't worry if it becomes zero, Date objects are very very smart - see [Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Honestly, I googled literally your whole title and that was the first result. Utilize google please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
var yesterday = d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
```

Simply replace `- 1` with `- 2`, `- 3` and so on for the previous seven days.